# Passing generic function to a generic method

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have a piece code that fails to compile, and I cannot seem to understand why.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      lookupStuff(Main::lookup);
    }

    private static <T> void lookupStuff(Function<Class<T>,T> locator) {
       Integer i = locator.apply(Integer.class);
       String s = locator.apply(String.class);
    }

    private static <T> T lookup(Class<T> cls) {
       return null; // do some lookup
    }
}
```

Compiler fails with:

```
    Error:(12, 42) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>
    Error:(13, 40) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>
```

Comment: Your `locator` function takes a `Class<T>`, but you're passing a `Class<Integer>`. Why do you think this code should compile?

Comment: `lookupStuff` takes a function that works for a _specific_ `T`, not one that works for _all_ `T`.  You might be able to make this work with a custom functional interface, but even then I wouldn't be certain that the type inference will figure all this out.

Comment: This is not a duplicate and even if it was, it has nothing to do with casts

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks for the explanation, if you provide is as an answer I can accept it.